# OpenLayers template

Tags: openlayers

I am currently doing a research for how to build a web map viewer. I decided to go with OpenLayers. I am now looking for templates as I do not think it is necessary to build from scratch. I found [this](https://github.com/county-of-simcoe-gis/SimcoeCountyWebViewer) and think it comes with ample functions. But somehow my search hasn't turned up very many results. Do you have additional recommendations for open source openlayer based map viewer templates that I can use?

Comment: "Web map viewers" are very diverse, there are not many templates. If you want you can look into this: https://github.com/meggsimum/wegue
The example you found looks like a very powerful tool, but it's a completely finished web app, not a framework you can easily take and customize for your own needs. 

What exactly do you want to show, who is your target audience, how does your data look like? Do you want it to be full screen or do you want to embed it into an existing website?

Comment: So my audience is professionals. They should have access to a couple of tools and it should have a clean and professional design. And I want it to be full screen. I also like the one that comes with geoexplorer but I haven't found it as an isolated project. The data is wms raster and basemaps. Also I need some linestrings maybe in an sql database or as wfs.

Comment: i really like this one: https://breitband-in-sh.de/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For many tools there are official openlayers examples (like [measure](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/measure.html) or [draw](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-features.html?q=draw)).

This is a nice layerswitcher to use out-of-the-box: https://github.com/walkermatt/ol-layerswitcher.

You can also have a look at [ol-ext](https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/), which is a third-party software that gives you some custom controls like a searchbar, overview map, etc. Keep in mind that this software is not affiliated or maintained by openlayers.

A general remark about modern web map design: less is definitely more. Do not try to rebuild desktop gis software, a web viewer should do exactly that, view data in the web. While the viewer of https://breitband-in-sh.de/ is powerful, about 60% of its tools (or information) might be just obsolete, distracting the user from the data. Be aware who your customers are, show them what they really want to know and you can savely leave out all the rest.

Comment: okay thanks. I will mark this answer as being accepted as it points out that templates do not make that much sense. Every solution needs so much tailoring that it is better to just take openlayers and add plugins to it.